# ng-select not displaying search values properly after pasting in values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

When trying to update array of strings acting as the model for ng-select, the values do not display properly in the search box itself.

[image]

the values that are showing up properly, are the ones that are selected from the dropdown, the ones that do not display properly are numbers I am trying to add on to the list manually

select box in template:

```
<ng-select
 id="oNumberSelect"
 [items]="ownerNumberResults | async"
 [typeahead]="typeAhead$"
 bindLabel="desc"
 bindValue="code"
 dropdownPosition="bottom"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedOwnerNumbers"
 (ngModelChange)="handleSelectionChange()"
 [multiple]="true"
 [searchable]="true"
 multiple="true"
 style="overflow-y: auto; width: 100%"
 appendTo="body"
 (paste)="handlePaste($event)"
 minTermLength="3"
 [addTag]="true"
   >
</ng-select>
```

methods referenced:

```
handlePaste(pasteEvent: ClipboardEvent): void {
 pasteEvent.stopPropagation();
 pasteEvent.preventDefault();
 const clipStrings:string[] = [...pasteEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text').trim().split(/[\s,)]+/)]

 this.selectedOwnerNumbers = [...this.selectedOwnerNumbers, ...clipStrings];
}

searchOwnerNumbers(): void {
 this.ownerNumberResults = this.typeAhead$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  debounceTime(500),
  switchMap(term => {
    return this.ownerHttpService.searchOwnerProperty('ownerNumber', term);
   }
  )
 );
}

handleSelectionChange(): void {
 console.log(this.selectedOwnerNumbers)
}
```

select variables:

```
selectedOwnerNumbers: string[];
typeAhead$ = new Subject<string>();
ownerNumberResults: Observable<Option[]>;
```

I have tried using sets, arranging arrays differently, concatenating the pasted values, but i cant get them to show up in the UI correctly

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens if the bindValue and bindLabel are different.

try changing the handle paste logic like this

```js
  handlePaste(pasteEvent: ClipboardEvent) {
    pasteEvent.stopPropagation();
    pasteEvent.preventDefault();
    const clipStrings: string[] = [
      ...pasteEvent.clipboardData
        .getData('Text')
        .trim()
        .split(/[\s,)]+/),
    ];
    this.selectedOwnerNumbers.push(this.ownerNumberResults.find(result => result.desc === clipStrings[0]).code);
    this.selectedOwnerNumbers = [...this.selectedOwnerNumbers]
  }
```